# Non-CMake library distributed via vcpkg to CMake consumers - CMake config or Find module?

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I write a library that is built with Visual Studio (msbuild).

I distribute binaries only of the library via vcpkg (I use a private vcpkg registry. The `portfile.cmake` for the port simply downloads a zip file of the binaries and headers and places them in the vcpkg install tree).

I have a client that is using CMake.

I can integrate vcpkg (manifest mode) into CMake and find_package() finds vcpkg ports except for mine.

I've arrived at the point that I think I need to distribute either a CMake config (`<my-package>-config.cmake`) or a CMake find module (`Find<my-package>.cmake`).

All of the books I've read for CMake seem to assume that you can easily export your CMake targets to create a CMake config. Since I don't build my library with CMake I'm not sure how to get a Targets.cmake.

The documentation I'm reading on CMake find modules begins discussing resolving dependencies using `CMakeFindDependencyMacro` and `find_dependency()` but vcpkg also manages dependencies (this was the whole reason I distributed my library via vcpkg).

What's the solution here; CMake config or find module?

How does one write either if the project is not built with CMake?

Comment: I'd write Find-module. `find_dependency` is for specifying usage requirements for your library. Vcpkg only acquires dependencies and doesn't add any compiler flags to tell buildsystem that you use these dependencies.

Comment: @Osyotr thank you for validating that. This is the path I've pursued. The last step for me is trying to get the vcpkg_installed paths without using paths of the machine on which the module is built, i.e., building a relocatable module.

Comment: Example of a relocatable Find-module from my project: https://gist.github.com/Osyotr/709e71a91a3b277b01b684a0d638e758